# multipart/form-data rfc 1867 parsing

Tags: http, go

There was an error parsing the multipart form. The following attempts have been made, but are not being resolved: I don't know if Golang doesn't support rfc 1867. Thank you for your help.

```
POST /uploadFile.htm HTTP/1.1
Host: myserver
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 368
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x

--AaB03x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=BbC04y

--BbC04y
Content-Disposition: file; filename="file1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

... contents of file1.txt ...
--BbC04y
Content-Disposition: file; filename="file2.gif"
Content-Type: image/gif

...contents of file2.gif...
--BbC04y--
--AaB03x--
```

```golang
err := request.ParseMultipartForm(1024)
log.Printf("value %v", request.MultipartForm.Value)
log.Printf("file %v", request.MultipartForm.File)
```

If you look at the logs, here's the following

```
 value map[file:[--BbC04y
Content-Disposition: file; filename="file1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

... contents of file1.txt ...
--BbC04y
Content-Disposition: file; filename="file2.gif"
Content-Type: image/gif

...contents of file2.gif...
--BbC04y--]
file map[]
```

What should I do to parse the multi-part form?

Comment: I believe the first Content-Type should be multipart/mixed

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. But you are embedding a multipart/form-data as the first and only part inside a multipart/form-data. That's not how it is supposed to be used and that's not what browsers create if a form is submitted with multipart/form-data. So the problem might more be a broken client, not the server.

Comment: I was confirmed in one case. Although it is a multipart/from-data request, we confirmed that there is a multipart/from-data in the body part. This means the case.
In the example section of paragraph rfc 1867 6, you can view the request with multipart/from-data rather than multipart/mxied.

Comment: The part I want to do is to parse the boundary part of the body part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import "mime/multipart"
...
mr := multipart.NewReader(r.Body, boundary)
for {
    p, err := mr.NextPart()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
...
```

You can now log p after every part to check the format and extract data

Comment: Thank you, we've modified it in that way.